# Proving the inequality $\angle A+\angle COP < 90^\circ$ in $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, geometric-inequalities

> In an acute angled $\triangle ABC$, $AP \perp BC$and $O$ is its circumcenter. If $\angle C \ge \angle B + 30^\circ$, then prove that $$\angle A + \angle COP < 90^\circ$$

[image]

### My Attempt:

Extending the line $AP$ to the circumferential point $D$, I connected $O,D$ and $C,D$ and got two lines $OD$ and $CD$ as such below

[image]

Given that, $\angle C \ge \angle B + 30^\circ$ and so from that I got

$\angle C +\angle B+ \angle A \ge \angle B + \angle B +\angle A + 30^\circ \implies 180^\circ \ge 2\angle B + \angle A + 30^\circ \implies 150^\circ - \angle A \ge 2\angle B$

$2\angle B \le 150^\circ - \angle A$.....(1)

In right angled $\triangle APC, \angle APC = 90^\circ$

So, $\angle PAC = 90^\circ - \angle C$

After that, we know that $\angle COD = 2\angle DAC$

$\angle COD = 2(90^\circ - \angle C) \implies 180^\circ - \angle COD = 2\angle C$

$180^\circ - \angle COD \ge 2\angle B + 60^\circ \implies 180^\circ - 60^\circ - \angle COD \ge 2\angle B$

$120^\circ - \angle COD \ge 2\angle B$.....(2)

Notice that, both ($150^\circ - \angle A$) and ($120^\circ - \angle COD$) are greater than or equal to $2\angle B$.

So, how could I show the relation between ($150^\circ - \angle A$) and ($120^\circ - \angle COD$). **Or, any other way to prove for the desired inequality?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is very hard, whic contest is it?

Comment: @greedoid I know that you are doing fun with me. You are  a very expert mathematician. I thought that it would be easy for any other professional like you. And your answer is **BANGLADESH MATH OLYMPIAD**.

Comment: I'm not doing fun out of anybody and thus neither with you. At first I thought that it was some IMO problem.

Comment: @greedoid Oh my God!! Forgive me. I can never think of that.

Comment: I thought equality in the hypothesis would imply equaility in the thesis, i.e. $\angle C - \angle B = 30° \Rightarrow \angle COP + \angle A = 90°$. But it doesn't look like it is correct... By the way, it could be useful to observe that $\angle OAP = \angle C-\angle B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, afterall this is an IMO 2001 geometry problem and you can find two solutions, along with a solutions of the other problems from that year, here:

https://sms.math.nus.edu.sg/Simo/IMO_Problems/01.pdf

Comment: no, but thank you